# Converting input to integer and doing arithmetic in powershell

Tags: powershell

not sure how to convert a string to an integer and then do an "add 1" to it.  Here's what I'm trying to do:

1) Capture an IP address from a prompt

2) create list of variables with the increasing IPs as such:

```
$startIP = Read-Host 
$ip1 = $startIP
$ip2 = $ip1 + 1
$ip3 = $ip2 + 1
```

So for example, we'd input 10.0.0.1, and then `$ip2` would be 10.0.0.2 and so on.

I know I need to convert this to an integer after reading the input, but am unsure how to do that.  Many thanks!

Comment: what you are requesting would require more than just converting string to int. you will have to split the string, get the last token, convert that to an int then perform your arithmetic, and finally reconstructing the ip address.

Comment: Why would I need to split the string?

Comment: the ip is made of of segments separated by dot (.)

Comment: What should happen when you're adding `1` when the last IP-address component is `255`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found these functions that converts an IP to an Int64 and back

```
Function Convert-IpToInt64 () { 
    param ([String]$ip) 
    process { 
        $octets = $ip.split(".") 
        return [int64]([int64]$octets[0]*16777216 +[int64]$octets[1]*65536 +[int64]$octets[2]*256 +[int64]$octets[3]) 
    }
} 

Function Convert-Int64ToIp() { 
    param ([int64]$int) 
    process {
        return (([math]::truncate($int/16777216)).tostring()+"."+([math]::truncate(($int%16777216)/65536)).tostring()+"."+([math]::truncate(($int%65536)/256)).tostring()+"."+([math]::truncate($int%256)).tostring() )
    }
}
```

With that you can now convert the input to an something that can be incremented

```
$startIP = Read-Host 
$ip1 = Convert-IpToInt64 $startIP
$ip2 = $ip1 + 1
$ip3 = $ip2 + 1
```

Comment: Wow - so it was MUCH more complicated than I had thought.  Just tested these functions both ways and it seems to be working.  Thank you so much for the help - this solves my problem!